# Microsoft Virtual PC running Windows 7: VM Additions doesn't install correctly

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, microsoft-virtual-pc

Using Virtual PC 2007, if you attempt to install Virtual Machine Additions (VMAdditions.iso) on to a virtual Windows 7, the OS will crash and you will have to do a system restore. How to solve this?

Comment: Server 2005? Never heard of it

Comment: @Luke He probably means Virtual Server 2005, the predecessor to Hyper-V.

Comment: Ooooohhh ok. Did not know that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is solved by upgrading your copy of Virtual PC on the *host* computer to Virtual PC SP1. It can be found here:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24439

Also, if you're running VPC on Server 2005, upgrading to Server 2005 RC2 SP1 works as well.